# music website: how to make it work on android/blackberry/iphone/symbian?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, audio

How can I make my simple site, on which the user can choose to play a number of music clips by clicking on little "play" buttons on the page (think of Amazon's "preview" on their product pages for CDs), work on mobile devices?

[I originally created the page thinking only of desktop browsers, so currently it works by using Flash. I know that won't work at least on the iphone.]

Will I have to build a platform-specific app for all major mobile platforms to provide this kind of simple interface? If so, can you recommend a framework that will let me do this in "write once, run everywhere" fashion?

Many thanks for any insight!

~l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try: [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/)

Comment: thanks, hadn't crossed my mind that html5 answered my problem :)